# How do I enforce COSU in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cosu

I am currently trying to implement [COSU](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html) in React Native, specifically the functionality to lock down the user from accessing non-whitelisted apps at a certain time.

I would also need the non-whitelisted apps to display a lock screen.

How do I implement this in React Native?